# Why do I exceed the limit on maximum number of database connections

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website developed in PHP. The database being used is MySQL. Suddenly I started getting the following error on it:

`The maximum number of Database Connections has been exceeded. Please try again later.`

How to control number of database connections? or how can I exceed the limit on maximum number of database connections.

Comment: Did you try [Googling it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320728)?

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of your script (or when you're done with your database) you need to close the database connection to avoid this error. Please refer to PHP manual regarding the library you're using.

For [PDO see here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: From the page you link: "PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends".

Comment: @Austin Please ensure close is happens

Comment: Closing the connection at the end of the script is unnecessary and redundant because it will be automatically closed when the script ends.